# Calculate days between dates excluding repeated days and group

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have the following table with 3 columns: teacher, Initial & final date. Column  "Days" calculates difference in days for each row, but as some days are repeated with date ranges (highlighted), I would like to automatically calculate the "actual" working days grouped by teacher and if possible by month & teacher. Is this possible in Excel or Power BI?

[image: excel table]

Thanks for your help

Comment: For an Excel formula solution, you should be able to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75010653/excel-formula-or-vba-identifying-gaps-in-overlapping-dates-and-times but subtracting the total gaps from the date range (last date - first date) for each teacher.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using Power Query (available in Excel and Power BI).

**Starting table**:

| Teacher | Initial Date | Final Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Teacher 1 | 20/09/2022 | 29/11/2022 |
| Teacher 1 | 21/09/2022 | 30/11/2022 |
| Teacher 1 | 18/01/2023 | 27/03/2023 |
| Teacher 1 | 29/03/2023 | 12/06/2023 |
| Teacher 1 | 27/04/2023 | 10/07/2023 |
| Teacher 1 | 14/06/2023 | 04/10/2023 |
| Teacher 1 | 09/10/2023 | 20/12/2023 |
| Teacher 1 | 10/01/2024 | 18/03/2024 |
| Teacher 2 | 05/10/2022 | 13/12/2022 |
| Teacher 2 | 18/01/2023 | 27/03/2023 |
| Teacher 2 | 29/03/2023 | 12/06/2023 |
| Teacher 2 | 14/06/2023 | 04/10/2023 |
| Teacher 2 | 20/09/2023 | 27/11/2023 |
| Teacher 2 | 09/10/2023 | 20/12/2023 |
| Teacher 2 | 10/01/2024 | 18/03/2024 |

**The full Power Query script**:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Teacher", type text}, {"Initial Date", type date}, {"Final Date", type date}}),
    #"Add dates" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Dates", each List.Dates([Initial Date], Duration.Days([Final Date] - [Initial Date]) + 1, #duration(1, 0, 0, 0))),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Add dates",{"Teacher", "Dates"}),
    #"Expanded Dates" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Dates"),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Expanded Dates"),
    #"Add Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Duplicates", "Month", each Date.StartOfMonth([Dates]), type date),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Add Month", {"Teacher", "Month"}, {{"Days worked", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

**How it works**:

- Adds a new column of the list of dates between Initial and Final
- Expands that column into new Rows (a row per day)
- Remove duplicates on Teacher and Dates (removes overlaps)
- Adds a Month start column
- Group By on Teacher and Month, with a count of rows for Days worked

**Giving you a resulting table like**:

[image]

BTW: You missed an overlap for Teacher 1 on row 15.

Comment: This works perfectly, but the results for November 2022 (01/11/2022) shows 29 days and it should be 30 as final date in row 2 of the staring table is 30/11/2022 and it should be included... I refer to teacher 1

Comment: Great catch. Updated answer above. Updated step `#"Add dates"` to add one day to `[Final Date]`. There were other errors as well, like Teacher 2 for March 2024 should of been 18 (not 17). I have not updated the resulting tables (lazy).

Comment: Now, it is perfect! I will reuse the approach for sure. Tks

Comment: Splendid, please help mark the answer as Accepted for the benefit of all (check mark under the voting buttons).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible in Power BI. How do you define 'actual working days'? If you're talking about teachers, perhaps you don't include breaks? If so, you will need a Calendar or date table as a part of your model. In the Calendar Table, you will need a column for the actual working day. Could be something like 'Is Working Day'. There you will define the logic if a day should be considered a working day. You would create a relationship between your new date table and the table above. It is a best practice to create this calendar table. You could also use for other reports.

Comment: I just need the calculation in natural days..., obviously teachers make breaks and they don't work on weekends but in this case there is no need to build a personalized "working" calendar.

Comment: how do you define natural days?

Comment: 365-366 days in a year. A regular year from Jan 1st to Dec 31. Tks

Comment: You can create a custom column in power query to find the total days between the two columns: 
Duration.Days([final date]-[inititial date])

Comment: But this will only calculate the number of days between both dates for each row while I have to consider all rows for each teacher to get the righ number of days (that is, excluding those repeated)

Comment: @xaviergarciapous Then use the `GROUPBY` function in either DAX or Power Query.

Answer (score 0):

So just as a demonstration to see if it's on the right lines, define a lambda to find the gaps based on [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75010653/excel-formula-or-vba-identifying-gaps-in-overlapping-dates-and-times)

```
=LAMBDA(Starts,Ends,
LET(row, SEQUENCE(ROWS(Starts)),
maxSoFar, SCAN(0, row, LAMBDA(a,c, IF(c = 1, INDEX(Starts, 1), MAX(INDEX(Ends, c - 1), a)))), 
SUM(IF(Starts > maxSoFar, Starts - maxSoFar - 1, 0))))
```

Then the range of dates for teacher 1 minus the gaps is:

```
=LET(starts,C2:C9,
ends,D2:D9,
MAX(ends)-MIN(starts)-Gaps(starts,ends))
```

(you may wish to add 1 if counting inclusively of start and end date)

[image]

---

To calculate the gaps (and therefore the number of days worked) per month it's necessary to create a version of the Gap lambda which allows the calculation to be limited to a given window as follows

- Apply a filter to select the rows of data which overlap with the given window
- Insert the end date of the window at the end of the list of start dates
- Insert the start date of the window at the beginning of the list of finish dates

If the filters are empty, the lists will consist only of the start and finish dates of the window.

```
=LAMBDA(starts,ends,winstart,winend,
LET(wStarts, IFERROR(VSTACK(FILTER(starts, (starts <= winend) * (ends >= winstart)), winend + 1), winend + 1), 
wEnds, IFERROR(VSTACK(winstart - 1, FILTER(ends, (starts <= winend) * (ends >= winstart))), winstart - 1),
maxSoFar, SCAN(0, wEnds, LAMBDA(a,c, MAX(c, a))), 
SUM(IF(wStarts > maxSoFar, wStarts - maxSoFar - 1, 0))))
```

You can create a table of teachers, months (spanning the lists of dates) and days worked per month as follows (or otherwise):

```
=LET(teachers,A2:A16,startDates,C2:C16,endDates,D2:D16,
firstDate,EOMONTH(MIN(startDates),-1)+1,
lastDate,EOMONTH(MAX(endDates),0),
nMonths,DATEDIF(firstDate,lastDate,"M")+1,
uTeachers,UNIQUE(teachers),
months,SEQUENCE(nMonths,1,0),
DROP(REDUCE({"","",""},uTeachers,LAMBDA(at,t,VSTACK(at,
    DROP(REDUCE({"","",""},EDATE(firstDate,months),LAMBDA(am,m,VSTACK(am,HSTACK(t,m,EOMONTH(m,0)-m+1-
      GapWindow(FILTER(startDates,teachers=t),FILTER(endDates,teachers=t),m,EOMONTH(m,0)))))),1)))),1))
```

and optionally use PivotBy to add totals:

```
=PIVOTBY(CHOOSECOLS(K2#,2),CHOOSECOLS(K2#,1),CHOOSECOLS(K2#,3),SUM)
```

[image]