Excel Sum Unique Times
Been looking and not able to find a solution.
Looking to find the sum of unique times for an excel sheet with >200 rows.
Eg.

In the image above, the total unique time would be 6 hours (2 hours from 12:00 - 14:00, 2 hours from 14:00 - 16:00, and 2 hours from 17:00 - 19:00).
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks
Don't know where to start on this one other than manually adding the unique times for each line and then summing.

By "unique" do you mean "full hours"?

@Michal I guess it means don't sum intersections twice.

Is your second duration (4.5) a typo? If not, please clarify.

Do the times cross dates? Also, we need to consider partial hour overlaps too, right?

I seem to remember doing a fairly simple answer to this using the Gap and Island principle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75010653/excel-formula-or-vba-identifying-gaps-in-overlapping-dates-and-times/75017863#75017863

@TomSharpe, learnt about this method - thank you! But would you check the result with input like 10/15/24 12:00 10/15/24 14:00
10/15/24 12:30 10/15/24 16:00
10/15/24 17:00 10/15/24 19:00
10/16/24 8:00 10/16/24 11:15
10/16/24 10:00 10/16/24 12:00
10/16/24 9:00 10/16/24 10:30?

Will do. It's always good to have your work checked!

The precondition for my answer is that the start times have to be in ascending order. This is mentioned in one of the comments, but I should have made it clearer. So it does give the correct result (a total gap of 14 hours), but only if you swap the last pair of values. I will add a sort option to my answer.

This is an Excel version of what I have created in DAX as per this question and it uses the idea of flattening the 2-dimentional time data onto a 1-dimentional line:

=LET(
   start_times,A1:A3,
   end_times,B1:B3,
    timeline, SEQUENCE((MAX(end_times)-MIN(start_times))*1440, 1, MIN(start_times), 1/1440),
    overlaps, MMULT((timeline>=TRANSPOSE(start_times))*(timeline<=TRANSPOSE(end_times)), SEQUENCE(ROWS(start_times), 1, 1, 0)),
    unique_overlaps, SUM(--(overlaps > 0)),
    unique_overlaps &  " minutes"
)

The proposed solution works with one minute granularity (1440 in the formula 24*60). It can be adjusted if the input data has higher or lower granularity.


So, I researched the formula. It works, but algorithm is very poor.

Max time interval is 1048576 minutes (~2 yrs.) Practically, it's not expected. It can be a limit for dynamic arrays, who knows.

The task is to combine (or sum) overlapping time intervals.
There are two options: a worksheet formula or a user-defined function.
Solution 1
Variant using Tom Sharpe's prompt (it looks the best) (@TomSharpe)
Generally, it consists of one sort and one loop (2 loops in formula version due to some limitation; this can be trespassed but will be more complicated little bit).
Formula
Input: TimeIntervals.
=LET(ti,SORT(TimeIntervals),st,TAKE(ti,,1),
me,SCAN(0,TAKE(ti,,-1),LAMBDA(a,i,MAX(i,a))),mes,VSTACK(0,DROP(me,-1)),
SUM(MAP(me,st,mes,LAMBDA(m,s,e,m-MAX(s,e))))*24)

UDF
Function SumTimes(r As Range) As Double
  Dim a, i As Long, j As Long, ub As Long
  Dim ms As Double, mf As Double, Tot As Double
  a = Application.Sort(r): ub = UBound(a, 1): mf = 0
  For i = 1 To ub
    ms = IIf(a(i, 1) > mf, a(i, 1), mf)
    If a(i, 2) > mf Then mf = a(i, 2)
    Tot = Tot + mf - ms
  Next
  SumTimes = Tot * 24
End Function

Algorithm
Algorithm here is very simple:

For the first interval, the duration calculates as is. For subsequent intervals, the duration calculates:

As is if there is no intersection with the previous (row #5);
As the additional time to the previous if they intersect (row #4).

Finally, durations sum.
Solution 2
The solution based on the fast algorithm with low memory consumption which includes one loop to collect data, one sort, and one loop to get the result. It works with unlimited number of intervals (in formula version, limited by Excel dynamic arrays, <2^19 intervals) with unlimited timestamp values.
The end time of an interval should be greater or equal the start time. No preliminary sort is required.

Formula
Inputs:

StartTimes - start time range, A2:A4 on the picture
EndTimes - end time range, B2:B4 on the picture

=LET(et,REDUCE("",EndTimes,LAMBDA(a,i,VSTACK(a,HSTACK(i,1)))),
  tl,SORT(DROP(REDUCE(et,StartTimes,LAMBDA(a,i,VSTACK(a,HSTACK(i,-1)))),1)),
  INDEX(REDUCE({0,0,0},SEQUENCE(ROWS(tl)),LAMBDA(a,i,
    LET(t,INDEX(tl,i,1),a1a,INDEX(a,1),a2a,INDEX(a,2),stst,a2a+INDEX(tl,i,2),
      VSTACK(IF(a2a=0,t,a1a),stst,INDEX(a,3)+IF(stst=0,t-a1a,0))
    ))),3)*24)

UDF
SumTimes function requires the start/end times range as the input.
=SumTimes(A2:B4)

Option Explicit

Function SumTimes(r As Range) As Double
  Dim a, v, i As Long, j As Long, ub As Long, m As Long
  Dim St As Double, Ss As Long, Tot As Double
  a = r: ub = UBound(a, 1): m = 2 * ub
  ReDim v(1 To m, 1 To 2)
  For i = 1 To ub
    v(2 * i - 1, 1) = a(i, 1): v(2 * i - 1, 2) = -1
    v(2 * i, 1) = a(i, 2): v(2 * i, 2) = 1
  Next
  a = Application.Sort(v)
  For i = 1 To m
    j = Ss + a(i, 2)
    If j = 0 Then Tot = Tot + a(i, 1) - St
    If Ss = 0 And j = -1 Then St = a(i, 1)
    Ss = j
  Next
  SumTimes = Tot * 24
End Function

Algorithm
Algorithm puts both start and end time stamps into a single array then sorts it. Then it iterates from the least time stamp counting the match between ends and starts. As soon as the zero count has reached, the time interval adds to the total time.

First off, I'll assume the sheet/data is sorted by Start Time (Ascending), then End Time (Ascending).  This makes the work much easier as things are organized properly.
Once you get the results, you can always sort back another way.
The logic I used here, is to assume the first row I come to is "complete" .. and then compare following rows to previous ones, to "reposition" the start time to the end time of the previous row .. IF there is overlap.
I added this column for "Actual start"
in D2:
=MAX(A2,OFFSET(B2,-1,0,1,1),OFFSET(D2,-1,0,1,1))
This picks out the latest start date possible ... from the original start date of the column, compared to the end date of the previous row ... and the actual start of the previous row (in event of multiple row overlap .. need to consider it - because it'll be the end date of the first row of the set .. begin pulled forward)
and then calc the duration:
in E2:
=IF(D2<B2,B2-D2,0)
the IF to help exclude an negative durations that arise, such as from an overlapping date range like:


2024-10-17 Attempting to improve based on comments from Michal and rotabor
Please see the previous answers in edit history

For each entry

Get overlapping entries

overlap_dur, LAMBDA(i, j,
    MAX(MIN(end(dates, i), end(dates, j)) 
  - MAX(start(dates, i), start(dates, j)), 0)
    ),
has_overlap, LAMBDA(i, MAP(idx, LAMBDA(j, overlap_dur(i, j) > 0))),


If the entry has no overlapping entries before it,

calculate unique hours based on these entries
24 * (MAX(end(overlapping, 0)) - MIN(start(overlapping, 0)))
zero otherwise



=LET(
    last_entry, INDEX(B:B, XMATCH(TRUE, B:B <> "", , -1)),
    dates, A2:last_entry,
    start, LAMBDA(dates, i, INDEX(dates, i, 1)),
    end, LAMBDA(dates, i, INDEX(dates, i, 2)),
    idx, SEQUENCE(ROWS(dates)),
    overlap_dur, LAMBDA(i, j,
        MAX(MIN(end(dates, i), end(dates, j)) - MAX(start(dates, i), start(dates, j)), 0)
    ),
    has_overlap, LAMBDA(i, MAP(idx, LAMBDA(j, overlap_dur(i, j) > 0))),
    unique_hours, REDUCE(
        {"Start", "End", "Duration"},
        idx,
        LAMBDA(acc, i,
            LET(
                overlapping, FILTER(dates, has_overlap(i)),
                dur, IF(
                    AND(i > 1, SUM(--TAKE(has_overlap(i), IF(i > 1, i - 1, 1)))),
                    0,
                    24 * (MAX(end(overlapping, 0)) - MIN(start(overlapping, 0)))
                ),
                VSTACK(acc, HSTACK(start(dates, i), end(dates, i), dur))
            )
        )
    ),
    VSTACK(
        HSTACK("Total Unique Hours", "", SUM(INDEX(unique_hours, , 3))),
        HSTACK("Calculation", "", ""),
        unique_hours
    )
)






It seems this giant formula works. I hope you don't use the per minute table. Well done.

Thanks for the kind words @rotabor! I'm hoping P.b, JvDV or you could shorten it ;)

It's an amazing formula and not something I could ever do but seems that it doesn't handle data expanding over more than 1 year.

@nkalvi - it also doesn't work for multiple days extending between two or more months - https://i.sstatic.net/nSk7MaqP.png

@nkalvi - rotabor was not impressed by my effort but perhaps you could combine my approach with yours.  Expand each datetime, not based on hour but the whole datetime and stack them.

@Michal, would you please check the update when you get a chance? Will test more tomorrow. Thanks again for suggesting the improvement.

@nkalvi I don't think it's quite right and for longer time scales it does take a while to re-calculate - https://i.sstatic.net/9nUrvVRK.png

@rotabor, I'm trying with a different method. Would you please check if you get a chance?

start, LAMBDA(dates, i, INDEX(dates, i, 1)) is the good idea to enhance INDEX! But I upvoted your answer already.

Thanks @rotabor, I was only wondering if you see any obvious issues. Since I'm not expanding, this one performs much better. And of course I appreciate your vote - it means a lot!

There may be ways that the efficiency of this can be improved — it currently performs more than 2N² calculations for N date-pairs
=LET(startDates, A2:A4,
     endDates, B2:B4,

     linearS, TOCOL(startDates),
     linearE, TOCOL(endDates),
     seq, SEQUENCE(ROWS(linearS)),

     datesTable, HSTACK(linearS, linearE),
     descDates, SORTBY(datesTable, linearS, -1),
     ascDates, SORTBY(datesTable, linearE, 1),

     early, BYROW(linearS,
                  LAMBDA(_d, REDUCE(_d, seq, LAMBDA(_a,_v,
                                                    LET(_s, INDEX(descDates, _v, 1),
                                                        _e, INDEX(descDates, _v, 2),
                                                        IF(_a=MEDIAN(_s, _a, _e), _s, _a)
                                                    )
                                             )
                             )
                  )
            ),
     late, BYROW(linearE,
                 LAMBDA(_d, REDUCE(_d, seq, LAMBDA(_a,_v,
                                                   LET(_s, INDEX(ascDates, _v, 1),
                                                       _e, INDEX(ascDates, _v, 2),
                                                       IF(_a=MEDIAN(_s, _a, _e), _e, _a)
                                                   )
                                            )
                            )
                 )
            ),

     timeBlocks, UNIQUE(HSTACK(early, late)),
     durations, INDEX(timeBlocks, , 2)-INDEX(timeBlocks, , 1),
     SUM(durations)
)

The first thing we do is force our startDates and endDates to each be in a single Column array (linearS and linearE) — this means we no longer need to worry about the orientation of the input.  We also create a SEQUENCE of numbers, from 1 to however many dates we are dealing with.  This will be used to control loops later.
Then, we create a two-column datesTable that combines our Linear Dates, and two sorted copies: Descending by Start Date, and Ascending by End Date.
Next, comes the two big calculations:

For every Start Date, we set an Accumulator (_a) to to the Start Date, then loop through our dates from "Last Start Date" to "First Start Date" (descDates).  (This loop is controlled using the sequence we created earlier)  If _a falls between the current Start and End dates, then we change _a to the current Start Date before checking the next Start/End pair.
For every End Date, we set an Accumulator (_a) to to the End Date, then loop through our dates from "First End Date" to "Last End Date" (ascDates).  (This loop is controlled using the sequence we created earlier)  If _a falls between the current Start and End dates, then we change _a to the current End Date before checking the next Start/End pair.

This will walk every Start Date forwards through overlapping time-blocks, to as early as possible; and it will walk every End Date backwards through overlapping time-blocks, to as late as possible.  We combine early and late into a two-column array and then take the unique timeBlocks.  (i.e. "12:00–14:00" and "13:00–15:00" will become "12:00–15:00" and "12:00–15:00"… we then only need one of those two records!)
Finally, we subtract all of the Start Dates from the End Dates for our timeBlocks to get their durations, and then add it all up to get out total time elapsed.
